# How can I mutate only specific rows?

Tags: r, rows, dplyr

For example, how can I divide by 2 only the rows ranging from 25 to 45 on a dataset that has 100 rows?

Comment: Please provide a complete example.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

BOD is a builtin 6x2 data frame whose columns are both numeric.  These solutions require dplyr 1.0.0 or later.

**1)** This checks whether the row number is between 3 and 5 inclusive and if so divides by 2 and otherwise does not.  If some of the columns are not numeric then replace `everything()` with `where(is.numeric)` so that the division only applies to the numeric columns.

```
library(dplyr)

BOD %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(row_number() %in% 3:5, ./2, .)))
```

**2)** This alternative uses magrittr's %<>% operator but it does overwrite BOD in the sense that it will leave a modified version of BOD whereas the above preserves it and returns the result.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

BOD[3:5, ] %<>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ ./2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the rows which are in range, divide and replace.

```
rows <- 25:45
df[rows, ] <- df[rows, ]/2
```

---

With a reproducible example dividing row numbers 3 to 4.

```
set.seed(456)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(100, 5), b = sample(100, 5))
df
#   a  b
#1 35 78
#2 38 31
#3 85 73
#4 27 79
#5 25 90

rows <- 3:4
df[rows, ] <- df[rows, ]/2
df
#     a    b
#1 35.0 78.0
#2 38.0 31.0
#3 42.5 36.5
#4 13.5 39.5
#5 25.0 90.0
```